# mySQL select and group by values

Tags: sql, mysql

I'd like to count and group rows by specific values. This seems fairly simple, but I can't seem to do it.

I have a table set up similar to this:

```
Table: Ratings
id pID uID rating
1  1   2     7
2  1   7     7
3  1   5     4
4  1   1     1
```

id is the primary key, piD and uID are foreign-keys. Rating contains values between 1 and 10, and only between 1 and 10.

I want to run some statistics and count the number of ratings with a certain value. In the example above, two have left a rating of 7.

So I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count' , 'rating'
FROM 'ratings'
WHERE pID= '1'
GROUP BY `rating`
ORDER BY `rating`
```

Which yields the nice result as:

```
count  ratings
1      1
1      4
2      7
```

I'd like to get the mySQL query to include values between 1 and 10 as well.

For example:

```
Desired Result
count  ratings
1      1
0      2
0      3
1      4
0      5
0      6
2      7
0      8
0      9
0      10
```

Unfortunately, I'm relatively new to SQL and I've been reading through everything I could get my hands on for the past hour, but I can't get it to work. I've been leaning along the lines of a some type of JOIN.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it'd be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any function, or methodology, to directly get a range of ratings like what you need. The only thing I can think of is to have a table containing the allowable range of ratings.

```
Table: AllowedRatings
rating
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Then use this to do a subquery with your ratings table:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM ratings 
         WHERE ratings.rating = AllowedRatings.rating 
           AND pid = '1'
       )
     , rating
FROM AllowedRatings
ORDER BY rating
```

I know this could also be done by a join, but that would be more complicated, and I'm honestly a bit too tired to work it out, or set up a DB correctly to test it, but the subquery method should work.

The advantage of this method is that you could put more information in for your ratings, like a description (eg: `1 = 'Sucks', 3 = 'Meh', 5 = 'Ok', 7 = 'Worthwhile', 10 = 'Amazing!'`) or change your range without having to edit hard-coded values

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. As I said, I'm fairly new to SQL and couldn't get the syntax right for the subquery when I tried it earlier.

Comment: may be your query is more simple for user, but much more complicated for mysql. "The advantage of this method is that you could put more information in for your ratings" this is not advantage of this method. using joins in mysql allows do this too.

Comment: @jerkms I didn't mean an advantage to using subqueries, I meant the advantage to having a second table store the information for the allowable rating levels. I probably should have phrased that a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

create regular or temporary table with numbers from 1 to 10 and LEFT JOIN it with yours. like:

```
SELECT COUNT(`rating`) AS `count` , `rating`
FROM `numbers`
LEFT JOIN `ratings` ON `numbers`.`n` = `ratings`.`rating`
WHERE pID= '1'
GROUP BY `numbers`.`n`
```

ps: ORDER BY here is ambiguous, because by default GROUP BY already sort the results

pps: you have a number of typos in your query with using ' instead of `

Answer (score 0):

You could do this pretty simply in php.

```
//do mysql query
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
     //$i + 1 is this rating
     //check if this ratings count is in result array
     //else use 0 as count
     //echo count
}
```