# What is the SQL query to select the id's of same name?

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
Table Name:`sample`  

   id|name
    1|rama
    2|seetha
    3|rama
    4|seetha
    5|rama
    6|seetha
    7|rama
    8|seetha
```

I need to display the unique `name` and `id`.

The following is the query I have used to get the name and ids:

```
"SELECT sample.id, sample.name FROM sample group by name"
```

Two names are displaying but I need the different ids used for that name.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528187/mysql-select-and-group-by-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to look in to [GROUP functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sample.id) AS ids, sample.name FROM sample group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use GROUP BY to group all records by name and GROUP_CONCAT function to join the ids for the name:

```
SELECT s.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.id ORDER BY s.id ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS ids FROM `sample` s GROUP BY s.name;
```